# This kind of sql logic, function or procedure?

Tags: sql, oracle, procedure

I'm fairly new to procedures and stuff especially Oracle.
I've been learning the basics of PLSQL which is not very different from actual programming.

But I am not sure about the conventions and standards.

Given:
I have a logic that takes in parameters, deletes, inserts records on DIFFERENT tables based on the parameters (more like a batch process) and returns a flag if everything was successful or not.

Questions:
1.) Is this logic fit as a function or a procedure?
*Based on what I researched, we use function when we want to RETURN something, and procedure when we want to DO (insert/update/delete) something. But my logic does both.

2.) Can I call a procedure inside a function in PLSQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Yes, it's definitely a fitting a procedure

2) You can call procedures within both procedures and functions

If your batch process becomes complex, try to split it into multiple subprograms (procedures and functions) encapsulate them into a plsql package. It all depends on the complexity of your process

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply sir! Yeah I've read about packages.
I have a follow-up question sir, so if I put everything in a package, I'd have 1 proc (like a main method or something like that) that calls all other functions/procs. Is this correct?

Comment: yes, that's correct. your can create within a package a procedure for every task you want to run, and then have a main procedure that executes these tasks in whatever order you want and so on

Comment: That's a design decision.  Just as with Java we can decide which procedures and functions to expose in the package spec and which to keep private in the body.  Most packages do not have anything analogous to a `main()` method; rather they have several different public procedures, even if the package is organised around a single business transaction.

Answer (score 1):

> "returns a flag if everything was successful or not."

Don't do this.  Flags are bad, because they are easy to ignore.  If the called program fails it should raise an exception.  Exceptions are good because the calling program must  acknowledge them, and decide how to handle them.

If the called program succeeds it doesn't have to do anything; in the absence of a raised exception the calling program just assumes success and moves on.

> "I will be calling these procedures in Java"

Java handles Exceptions.  A PL/SQL exception will hurl a Java `SQLException`, so use a `try` `catch` block when calling the stored procedure.  You can use `SQLException.getCode()` to get the error number.  [Every Oracle error has one](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17766/toc.htm).  Also, we can use the magic range -20999 to -20000 to define custom exception.  [Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/errors.htm#i3329).

Comment: Thanks sir, I'll keep this in mind and read about handling exceptions in PLSQL. An idea on top of my head is to catch exceptions and THEN set values to a flag. Is this still a bad practice? 

P.S. I will be calling these procedures in Java :)